# Making sense from GHC profiler

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I'm trying to make sense from GHC profiler. There is a rather simple app, which uses `werq` and `lens-aeson` libraries, and while learning about GHC profiling, I decided to play with it a bit.

Using different options (`time` tool, `+RTS -p -RTS` and `+RTS -p -h`) I acquired entirely different numbers of my memory usage. Having all those numbers, I'm now completely lost trying to understand what is going on, and how much memory the app actually uses.

This situation reminds me the phrase by Arthur Bloch: "A man with a watch knows what time it is. A man with two watches is never sure."

Can you, please, suggest me, how I can read all those numbers, and what is the meaning of each of them.

Here are the numbers:

`time -l` reports around **19M**

```
#/usr/bin/time -l ./simple-wreq
...
        3.02 real         0.39 user         0.17 sys
  19070976  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
     21040  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         0  swaps
         0  block input operations
         0  block output operations
        71  messages sent
        71  messages received
      2991  signals received
        43  voluntary context switches
      6490  involuntary context switches
```

Using `+RTS -p -RTS` flag reports around **92M**. Although it says "total alloc" it seems strange to me, that a simple app like this one can allocate and release 91M

```
# ./simple-wreq +RTS -p -RTS      
# cat simple-wreq.prof
        Fri Oct 14 15:08 2016 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

           simple-wreq +RTS -N -p -RTS

        total time  =        0.07 secs   (69 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
        total alloc =  91,905,888 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE                             MODULE                          %time %alloc

main.g                                  Main                             60.9   88.8
MAIN                                    MAIN                             24.6    2.5
decodeLenient/look                      Data.ByteString.Base64.Internal   5.8    2.6
decodeLenientWithTable/fill             Data.ByteString.Base64.Internal   2.9    0.1
decodeLenientWithTable.\.\.fill         Data.ByteString.Base64.Internal   1.4    0.0
decodeLenientWithTable.\.\.fill.\       Data.ByteString.Base64.Internal   1.4    0.1
decodeLenientWithTable.\.\.fill.\.\.\.\ Data.ByteString.Base64.Internal   1.4    3.3
decodeLenient                           Data.ByteString.Base64.Lazy       1.4    1.4


                                                                                                             individual     inherited
COST CENTRE                                              MODULE                            no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                                                     MAIN                              443           0   24.6    2.5   100.0  100.0
 main                                                    Main                              887           0    0.0    0.0    75.4   97.4
  main.g                                                 Main                              889           0   60.9   88.8    75.4   97.4
   object_                                               Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal        925           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.2
    jstring_                                             Data.Aeson.Parser.Internal        927          50    0.0    0.2     0.0    0.2
   unstream/resize                                       Data.Text.Internal.Fusion         923         600    0.0    0.3     0.0    0.3
   decodeLenient                                         Data.ByteString.Base64.Lazy       891           0    1.4    1.4    14.5    8.1
    decodeLenient                                        Data.ByteString.Base64            897         500    0.0    0.0    13.0    6.7
....
```

`+RTS -p -h` and `hp2ps` show me the following picture and two numbers: **114K** in the header and something around **1.8Mb** on the graph.
[image: Memory Profiling]

And, just in case, here is the app:

```
module Main where

import Network.Wreq
import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = replicateM_ 10 g
  where 
    g = do
        r <- get "http://httpbin.org/get"
        print $ r ^. responseBody
                   . key "headers"
                   . key "User-Agent"
                   . _String
```

**UPDATE 1:** Thank everyone for incredible good responses. As was suggested, I add `+RTS -s` output, so the entire picture builds up for everyone who read it.

```
#./simple-wreq +RTS -s
...
     128,875,432 bytes allocated in the heap
      32,414,616 bytes copied during GC
       2,394,888 bytes maximum residency (16 sample(s))
         355,192 bytes maximum slop
               7 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       194 colls,     0 par    0.018s   0.022s     0.0001s    0.0022s
  Gen  1        16 colls,     0 par    0.027s   0.031s     0.0019s    0.0042s
```

**UPDATE 2**: The size of the executable:

```
#du -h simple-wreq
63M     simple-wreq
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A man with a watch knows what time it is. A man with two watches is never sure.

Ah, but what do does two watches show? Are both meant to show the current time in UTC? Or is one of them supposed to show the time in UTC, and the other one the time on a certain point on Mars? As long as they are in sync, the second scenario wouldn't be a problem, right?

And that is exactly what is happening here. You compare different memory measurements:

- the **maximum residency**
- the **total amount of allocated memory**

The maximum residency is the highest amount of memory your program ever uses at a given time. That's 19MB. However, the total amount of allocated memory is a lot more, since that's how GHC works: it "allocates" memory for objects that are garbage collected, which is almost everything that's not unpacked.

Let us inspect a C example for this:

```
int main() {
   int i;
   char * mem;

   for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      mem = malloc(19 * 1000 * 1000);
      free(mem);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Whenever we use `malloc`, we will allocate 19 megabytes of memory. However, we free the memory immediately after. The highest amount of memory we ever have at one point is therefore 19 megabytes (and a little bit more for the stack and the program itself).

However, in total, we allocate 5 * 19M, **95M total**. Still, we could run our little program with just 20 megs of RAM fine. That's the difference between **total allocated memory** and **maximum residency**. Note that the residency reported by time is always at least `du <executable>`, since that has to reside in memory too.

That being said, the easiest way to generate statistics is `-s`, which will show how what was the maximum residency from the Haskell's program point of view. In your case, it will be the **1.9M**, the number in your heap profile (or double the amount due to profiling). And yeah, Haskell executables tend to get extremely large, since libraries are statically linked.

Comment: Thank Zeta for your reply. I have one more question. The size of the binary is 63M. Does it mean that the binary was not fully loaded into the memory somehow?

Comment: @Slabko: I don't have a Unix environment to check the semantics of `time -l` at the moment, so that might not be 100% correct. However, I haven't found any actual man pages where `-l` is described. Which `time` do you use?

Comment: I use Mac OS 10.11 and embedded version of `time`. It uses POSIX's `getrusage`. Interestingly enough, `getusage` returns size in kb and 19070976 kb is a really big number. I tried GNU `time` on linux; with the binary size of 48M it still claims that maximum resident set size equals 32820Kb But I think, I received more than good answer for my question, and now I understand how I should read numbers of GHC profiler. I don't think that the way `time` works is relevant to the understanding of Haskell memory optimization in my case. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: The whole executable file doesn't necessarily need to be loaded at runtime. If the executable has a symbol table it could be larger than the actual code and data.

Answer (score 4):

`time -l` is displaying the (resident, i.e. not swapped out) size of the process as seen by the operating system (obviously). This includes twice the maximum size of the Haskell heap (due to the way that GHC's GC works), plus anything else allocated by the RTS or other C libraries, plus the code of your executable itself plus the libraries it depends on, etc. I'm guessing in this case the primary contributor to the 19M is the size of your exectuable.

`total alloc` is the total amount allocated onto the Haskell heap. It is not at all a measure of maximum heap size (which is what people usually mean by "how much memory is my program using"). Allocation is very cheap and allocation rates of around 1GB/s are typical for a Haskell program.

The number in the header of the hp2ps output "114,272 bytes x seconds" is something completely different again: it is the integral of the graph, and is measured in bytes * seconds, not in bytes. For example if your program holds onto a 10 MB structure for 4 seconds then that will cause this number to increase by 40 MB*s.

The number around 1.8 MB shown in the graph is the actual maximum size of the Haskell heap, which is probably the number you're most interested in.

You've omitted the most useful source of numbers about your program's execution, which is running it with `+RTS -s` (this doesn't even require it to have been built with profiling).